# Linux Get physical location from file and write contents

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems, file-location, raw-disk

I want to get the physical location of linux file, /root/f.txt and write(overwrite) some contents of file

1. File is /root/f.txt
2. lsblk command output:

```
# lsblk
NAME          MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
fd0             2:0    1    4K  0 disk
sda             8:0    0   16G  0 disk
├─sda1          8:1    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda2          8:2    0   15G  0 part
  ├─rhel-root 253:0    0 13.4G  0 lvm  /
  └─rhel-swap 253:1    0  1.6G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb             8:16   0    1G  0 disk
sr0            11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

Contents of file:

```
#cat /root/f.txt
This is new file ha ha ha
```

3. From 'filefrag' command I get pysical location of file

```
#filefrag -v /root/f.txt
Filesystem type is: 58465342
File size of /root/f.txt is 26 (1 block of 4096 bytes)
ext:     logical_offset:        physical_offset: length:   expected: flags:
 0:        0..       0:    1761827..   1761827:      1:             eof
/root/f.txt: 1 extent found
```

4. Here physical block starts at **1761827** and 1 block is of 4096.
   So physical location of file would be: 1761827 * 4096 = **7216443392**
5. I have only '/dev/sda' and I am trying to write at location 7216443392 with dd command as:

```
#sudo dd seek=7216443392 if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sda count=1 obs=1
1+0 records in
512+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.00699863 s, 73.2 kB/s
```

6. But when I saw contents of file /root/f.txt, output is still same

```
 #cat /root/f.txt
 This is new file ha ha ha
```

So either the physical location is not correct, or I do something wrong with dd. Please suggest.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to test by reading the block rather than overwriting the block?

Comment: IMO `filefrag` shows you not physical disk but location inside the LV.

Answer (score 0):

The initial `cat` pulls the file into the page cache. Then, you directly write to the block device using `dd`. At this point, the kernel has no reason to believe the page in memory is not consistent with disk, so the new contents you write to the block device are not reflected when you `cat` after `dd`.

To see the new data written using `dd`, sync(1) and [drop the page cache](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/d0a231f01e5b25bacd23e6edc7c979a18a517b2b/Documentation/admin-guide/sysctl/vm.rst#drop_caches) before running `dd`:

```sh
sync
sudo sh -c 'echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches'
```